Telegram Web Api меняет протокол https на http в url, тем самым не позволяя его осуществить
При отправке запроса на бек протокол ссылки меняется с https на http, тем самым не позволяя осуществить запрос, так как телеграмм его блокирует, доступа к беку у меня нет, поэтому не могу сказать, в чем конкретно может заключаться проблема
вот сам код:
const initData = window.Telegram.WebApp.initData;
const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
    console.log("a");
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://geckoshi-stage.up.railway.app/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ initData }),
        });
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
}


Какое отношение Telegram Web Api имеет к вызову fetch?

Это не Telegram, а сам сервер
$ curl v -X POST https://geckoshi-stage.up.railway.app/auth
[...]
< HTTP/2 307 
< date: Fri, 11 Oct 2024 08:19:42 GMT
< location: http://geckoshi-stage.up.railway.app/auth/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[...]

Судя по всему сервер неправильно настроен, а вы забыли добавить слеш (/) в конце адреса.
